# Improve NER label results on non-English text

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, spacy

I am working on some Medieval Latin text and was using various methods of NER such as CLTK (Latin Model), Spacy (Multilingual, Italian, Spanish Model) and StanfordNER (Spanish Model). When I used the non-Latin models I used the original Latin text as the translated one was not making any sense.

Fortunately Spacy Multilingual model managed to extract all Persons and Places of the sample documents but with additional words that I am not considering them as Entities. Moreover, the labels are incorrect.

Here is an example output:

```
{'LOC': ['Artali', 'Artalis', 'Bruges', 'Unde'],
'MISC': ['Marianum lu Tignusu'],
 'PER': ['Simone de Mazara',
  'Artalem de Alagona',
  'Apoca',
  'Coram',
  'Pero de Naso',
  'Pero Caruana',
  'Bartholomeo Xacara',
  'Testamur',
  'Artalis de Alagona',
  'Melite',
  'Simonis de Mazara',
  'Simonem',
  'Simone',
  'Mariano',
  'Artalis',
  'Artalem',
  'Simoni',
  'Panormi',
  'Renunciando']}
```

where the LOCATIONS should be: Panormi, Bruges, Melite and PERSONAL names should be all others except Unde, Apoca, Coram, Testamur, Renunciando which are neither locations nor personal names.

I was thinking of ignoring the labels and do some classification ML algorithm. The problem is that I do not have any training data available and the only possible usable corpus that I think it might be useful is Proiel treebank which labels proper nouns as NE. How would you go with such a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you have enough raw text you can try to train a custom Word2vec model (or other words embedding, or even use the ones from spacy maybe...).

This way you can build a basic mapping word -> vector and use this to compare your extracted terms. In theory terms with closer semantical meaning (cities vs cities, names vs names) should have more similar vectors (cosine is a generally good approach to compare these vectors).

Then if you classify yourself some terms as cities, and some as names you can try to do some custom classification (e.g: top n closest elements between cities and names for each new term you want to classify: if the top n most similar elements are in the "cities" group then your term is likely in the city group).

*This is just a basic idea and I have no idea how precise it would be.* I have been using it for quick classification without any training dataset (but raw text) and it performed decently well on my tasks with a lox number of categories. It is highly dependent on your example for each class and the quality of your word2vec tho. And it also handles polysemy rather poorly.

**Also:** *maybe have a look at https://datascience.stackexchange.com since this is not exactly code related but rather about the approach to use*